# Credentials when using "Remotes" in R package Description

Tags: r, r-package

I want to include the dependency on an R library which is available at a private gitlab project. To include it I use the the "Remotes:" tag in the DESCRIPTION file. Automatically installing the package fails naturally due to the missing credentials.

Is it possible to automatically ask for credentials while installing the package via the DESCRIPTION file?

The DESCRIPTION file looks like this:

```
Title: Some Title
Version: 1
Description: What the package does (one paragraph).
Depends: R (>= 3.4.4)
Imports:
    theRemotePackage
Remotes: url::https://path/to/the/gitlab/repo/theRemotePackage
LazyData: true
```

Can I add a line in this file to make it ask for credentials of *theRemotePackage*?

Thank you!

Comment: You can try setting the `GITLAB_PAT` environment variable before you try to install so in theory that will get passed to `auth_token=`. Having dependencies that aren't publicly available in general would be a nightmare so I don't think there's any plan to ask for credentials for each remote when installing.

Comment: Thank you. Generally I agree that it makes no sense to have too many packages that need credentials. The background is to break down one larger unpublished package into smaller packages that could be used autonomously for specific functionality and to depend on these in the main package.

Comment: I suspect the answer is "no". I think it would be seen as a security risk to automatically go to another site for portions of the installation. You might want to take a look at how BioConductor sets up its installation process. Or look at `devtools::install_github`.